# What is the correct way to declare this?

Tags: android, android-layout

What is the correct way to declare this? 
My errors are marked with `**asterisks**` (since bold does not work in code snippets)

I would greatly appreciate any help anyone can give me.

```
    setContentView(R.layout.**activity_main**);

    currentX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.**currentX**);

    currentY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.**currentY**);

    currentZ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.**currentZ**);

    maxX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.**maxX**);

    maxY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.**maxY**);

    maxZ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.**maxZ**);

}
```

Comment: You don't have an activity layout in res/layout called `activity_main` and that activity layout doesn't contain TextViews with id's `currentX`, `currentY`, `currentZ`, `maxX`, `maxY`, or `maxZ`. My guess is that, if you are sure you have these, you have imported the wrong resource file.

Comment: No that wasn t problemt i just had a wrong import

Comment: So the end of my comment was the problem... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you have imported the wrong **R** file is imported R file is of your project or **android.R**
Look and import correct **R** file that is your package name (**com.example.R**)